# Node.js app on Heroku returns "Process exited with status 127" in logs

Tags: node.js, heroku

I could not get my web page using node.js after deploying in heroku. I am getting the below error.

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

My log file content is below:

```
2017-07-29T12:59:20.918810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1

2017-07-29T13:00:02.740139+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=node-fgdp.herokuapp.com request_id=04e1aa35-0722-4947-a832-836884934abf fwd="223.30.48.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-07-29T13:00:04.519877+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=node-fgdp.herokuapp.com request_id=3ea243cd-db39-43eb-978a-c25c6682e8a0 fwd="223.30.48.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-07-29T13:00:25.971843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=node-fgdp.herokuapp.com request_id=6df0d3e1-4ccf-442d-a7d4-46951fb2dfd1 fwd="223.30.48.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-07-29T13:00:26.328156+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=node-fgdp.herokuapp.com request_id=e69ce3b6-2b4f-4701-8313-19a5e9152669 fwd="223.30.48.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2017-07-29T13:06:18.001304+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `heroku run` by user subhrajyotipradhan@gmail.com

2017-07-29T13:06:19.926935+00:00 heroku[run.9255]: Awaiting client

2017-07-29T13:06:19.947866+00:00 heroku[run.9255]: Starting process with command `heroku run`

2017-07-29T13:06:20.133990+00:00 heroku[run.9255]: State changed from starting to up

2017-07-29T13:06:24.521994+00:00 heroku[run.9255]: Process exited with status 127

2017-07-29T13:06:24.533168+00:00 heroku[run.9255]: State changed from up to complete
```

I deployed my code into Heroku and when starts run the generated URL I am getting the above error. My code is below:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "FGDP",
  "description": "Our sample Node to Heroku app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "method-override": "~2.3.7",
      "mongojs": "~2.4.0",
    "crypto-js": "~3.1.8",
    "express-session": "~1.14.2",
    "multer":"~1.3.0",
    "dotenv" : "~4.0.0"
  }
}
```

server.js:

```
var express=require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var session = require('express-session');
var multer  = require('multer')
var app=module.exports=express();
var server=http.Server(app);
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
var port=process.env.PORT;
var admin=require('./route/route.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json())    // parse application/json
app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT
app.use(session({secret: 'FGDPlexel',resave: true,saveUninitialized: true}));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})
var storage =multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
app.post('/login',admin.userlogin);
app.get('/getSessionValue',admin.getSession);
server.listen(port);
console.log("Server is running on the port"+port);
```

I have set the port using `dotenv` and the file is given below.

.env:

```
PORT=8989;
```

Here I need to run the app.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use dotenv. You can set environment variables from either the CLI or from the settings tab in the heroku dashboard. Read more about it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/126) dotenv doesn't work on Heroku in production environment. Use Heroku dashboard to set environment variables.

Comment: Can you help me how to set it ?